# How to clip border in react-native application?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Here's the image of what I want to achieve with the green button in the layout. 
[image: notice the border above the view B]

Notice the border above the view B? I want the border of the bottom bar to have a curve around it.

So to do this I've created views structure -

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

class OkScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'column',
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          flexGrow: 1
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            flexGrow: 1
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            borderWidth: 1
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: 150,
            borderTopWidth: 10,
            borderTopColor: 'white'
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              borderWidth: 10,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              height: 152,
              width: 152,
              borderRadius: 76,
              bottom: 40
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                borderRadius: 75,
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderWidth: 10,
                borderColor: 'white'
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 40
                }}
              >
                B
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default OkScreen
```

This approach did not work and it ends up looking like this -

[image: the border is all over the view B]

**What approaches should I take to make this work? Any suggestion(s) would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

You can add a white circular view behind the white view containing the button, give this circle the border needed, and give the button a zIndex = 3 and the containing view zIndex = 2.

use `position: absolute` to position views on top of each other, adjust it with top, bottom, left, right. A tip: use the StyleSheet component and keep all styles there and don't rely on points when setting width, height, etc.. use '%' or `const {width, height} Dimensions.get('window')` and use them to make your app responsive

Comment: or you can keep the button's zIndex as it's already contained in the view

Comment: That's a good idea... Am trying but not sure where I've to change. Any help? a snippet maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the yellow element instead using `radial-gradient` and `linear-gradient` like below *(not sure about the support in react native)*:

```css
.yellow {
  height:100px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) right bottom/calc(50% - 50px) 3px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) left bottom /calc(50% - 50px) 3px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%,transparent 49px,#000 50px,#000 52px,yellow 53px);
}

.green {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  margin: -40px auto;
  background:green;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow">

</div>
<div class="green">
</div>
```

You can also consider a mix of border and box-shadow to approximate this:

```css
.yellow {
  height:100px;
  background:yellow;
  border-bottom:2px solid;
}

.green {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  border-top-color:#000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: -17px auto;
  padding:2px;
  background:green content-box;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 10px #fff inset;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow">

</div>
<div class="green">
</div>
```